# pushViewController:animated: inside ScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a UINavigationController inside it I have a UIViewController handling a ScrollView just to use addSubview: and I am loading several UIViewController into the ScrollView.

I have a button referring to pushViewController:animated: but it does nothing.
I used self.parentViewController and self.presentedViewController but ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based off of the title of this question. The question however, is not really a question at all, really.

**UIViewControllers must be pushed form a UINavigationController. You cannot use a UIScrollView to push a view. You can use animations to move UIViews within the UIScrollView.**

Comment: Well, I know that but I need to push a new ViewController on the UINavigationController stack. I need to access the NavigationController and it is not responding to self.navigationController or self.parentViewController.navigationController...

Comment: Your view that parents the UIScrollView must not be a UINavigationController then.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `self.navigationController` or `self.parentViewController.navigationController` is pushing **`nil`** .

Initiate a UINavigationController:

```
UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:aViewController];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nav animated:YES];
[nav release];
```

Try this. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem. What should you do is create button or other view controllers dynamically and add them to UIView and then add this UIView to scrollView. You should add IBaction on runtime to every button and after that your navigation controller will work.

Answer (score 0):

If your UIViewController is child of navigation controller then

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:aViewController animated:YES]`

will a push a viewcontroller over the present one.
Thats it!.